# "{\"ErrorCode\":402,\"Message\":\"Received invalid JSON input.\"}" When trying to call restsharp to make call to Postmark

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, postmark

i'm trying to make a call to Postmarks email service RestAPI using restsharp in C# and get a "{\"ErrorCode\":402,\"Message\":\"Received invalid JSON input.\"}" error every time i send it even though i have set the data format to json, i have even tried a custom json serialize . im not sure if im setting up the Parameters properly or even it  this is the best way to achieve what i'm trying so any help and suggestions would be welcome.

```
public void SendRest(string emailAddress, string subject, string body, params string[] recipients)
    {
        var recipientString = "";
        foreach (var recipient in recipients)
        {
            recipientString = recipientString + recipient + ',';
        }

        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.postmarkapp.com/email");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("X-Postmark-Server-Token", "Valid-Token");

        request.AddParameter("From", "test@testington.co.uk");
        request.AddParameter("To", "robin.windon@hotmail.co.uk");
        request.AddParameter("Subject", "hi");
        request.AddParameter("TextBody", "this is a test");
        request.AddParameter("TrackOpens", true);
        request.AddParameter("TrackLinks", "None");


        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the parameters either as (serialized) POST parameters (in the body) or GET-parameters, I am not sure how restsharp does handle this.

But you are not sending any JSON in the POST body as required.

Should be something like this I guess:

```
var params = JSON.Stringify(
    {
        "From": "robin.windon...",
        "To": "",
        "Subject": "",
        "TextBody": "",
        "TrackOpens": "",
        "TrackLinks": ""
    }
);
request.AddParameter("application/json", params, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: JSON.Stringify() is for a javasscript objects isentit? how would i do think in c#?

Comment: Ah yes this is Javascript. Please google for that function in C# I don't know, but I am sure it's just as easy.